# OpenGL rendering in Windows XP with multiple video cards

Tags: windows, opengl, rendering, nvidia

I'm developing an OpenGL application for Windows XP. The target machine has 2 NVIDIA GeForce 9800GT video cards, which are needed because the application needs to have output 2 streams of analog video.

The application itself has two OpenGL windows, one for each video card. Each video card is connected to one monitor. As for the code, it's based on a [minimal OpenGL example](http://www.opengl.org/resources/code/samples/win32_tutorial/minimal.c).

How can I know if the application is utilizing both video cards for rendering?

At the moment, I don't care if the application only runs on Windows XP or only with NVIDIA video cards, I just need to know how the two are working.

Comment: Not sure if you already have the answer to this question, but still provided you with some pointers that might help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to read up on the **WGL_nv_gpu_affinity** extension. You create affinity masks and use wglMakeCurrent() in conjunction with them. Here are some pointers:

http://developer.download.nvidia.com/opengl/specs/WGL_nv_gpu_affinity.txt

[Pdf from NVidia.com](http://www.nvidia.com/content/nvision2008/tech_presentations/Professional_Visualization/NVISION08-8MP_HDR.pdf)

Cheers !

Comment: GPU affinity is not supported on Geforce. The options are Linux, or creating one window on each attached screen and taking the performance hit of not 'masking' the GPU.

Edit: Or activate SLI, if your application scales with it. The nVidia website has documentation on which type of workloads scale with SLI.

Answer (score 1):

I beleive you can gain such information from the [gDEBugger](http://www.gremedy.com/) for OpenGL based applications.

If it turns out your not using both cards, you can check out [Equalizer](http://www.equalizergraphics.com/) for parallel rendering, it's a great project.