# AMD equivalent to NvOptimusEnablement

Tags: gpu, amd-gpu

For Intel+NVIDIA dual-GPU "Optimus" setups, an application can export `NvOptimusEnablement` as explained in [OptimusRenderingPolicies.pdf](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/devzone/devcenter/gamegraphics/files/OptimusRenderingPolicies.pdf).  This option allows an application to ensure the use of the high-speed discrete GPU without needing profile updates or user interaction, which is usually desired for certain classes of applictions.

Is there an equivalent trick for systems with AMD GPUs (Windows-only is fine), and if so, what is it?  I have not been able to find any concrete information via Googling; only a lot of people asking the same question on various forums with no answers, or SO articles on the NVIDIA trick with a "maybe AMD has something similar, I don't know" comment.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to https://community.amd.com/thread/169965

> ```c
> extern "C"
> {
>   __declspec(dllexport) int AmdPowerXpressRequestHighPerformance = 1;
> }
> ```
>
> This will select the high performance GPU as long as no profile exists that assigns the application to another GPU.
>
> Please make sure to use a 13.35 or newer driver. Older drivers do not support this.

Comment: Excellent news, glad to see they finally tackled this. For anyone else coming along, the 13.35 drivers are about a year old, so this feature may be hit-and-miss for end-users for a while still but it should be reliable for developers to use.

Comment: My co-worker reports that it works with the latest (14.12) driver.  Unfortunately, we upgraded the driver last week, so I can't confirm if any earlier driver works.

Comment: Also, note the caveat that AMD puts on their drivers: _The AMD Catalyst Mobility driver supports only AMD Enduro platforms that are based on second and later generation AMD A-series APUs or third generation Intel Core family._

Comment: So if you have a Westmere or Sandy Bridge system, you might need a driver update from your laptop manufacturer (which might not be available), or a patched driver (google _leshcat_).

Answer (score 1):

This code will be ignored when you compile on non-windows machines:

```cpp
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <windows.h>
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) DWORD NvOptimusEnablement = 0x00000001;
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) DWORD AmdPowerXpressRequestHighPerformance = 0x00000001;
#endif
```