# How to Automate Setting Default GPU for Windows App

Tags: windows, powershell, qt, graphics, gpu

I am developing a C++ Windows Desktop application in Visual Studio 2022 using Qt 6.5 and want it to force it to use a dedicated GPU for rendering.

In Windows 10, to set the default GPU for my app, I go to `System > Display > Graphics settings`, then browse for my executable and choose `High performance`, which is linked to a dedicated GPU card on my system.

Is this process automatable? If so, is there any way to automate this using for example PowerShell, a registry key, Windows C++ API, or even python?

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: See if this [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27881472/503046) still works.